# Looking for good wording to indicate that "There are notes"

Tags: wording

In a view I want to indicate that there are *notes* (like annotations) taken on the displayed element (that can be viewed by opening a notepad).

Rather than displaying a notepad icon, I want to display a real sentence, like "There are notes.".

I am no native speaker. Is "There are notes." an understandable sentence? What would be a good sentence, indicating that there are notes in a notepad on the displayed element?

Comment: Simple is probably best, so "Notes" or "Notes here" are the shortest label I can think of.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are avoiding an icon?

Comment: is useful to know the number of notes or just that there are or there aren't notes?

Comment: @GauthamRaja At the moment I am just considering options. The view is entirely text based, so a short sentence would just fit in very well. But I might very well end up with an icon.

Comment: @rewobs There is a *notepad* panel that allows one free-form note. So there is only one note per item. But I could perhaps say something like "5 paragraphs of notes" or "3 lines of notes".

Comment: What is your definition of 'a note'? Is it just a remark/comment (no further action expected) or an issue (needs pursuying by someone) or a question (answer expected)?

Comment: In my case, it is just a remark/comment (no further action expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to Izhaki's answer would be to simply state:

*View Notes*

It's clear. Simple and straight to the point.

Comment: It would not necessarily have to be "clickable" in my case, but it could - I like this proposition very much.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps instead of "There are notes" you also deliver the amount of notes as this may be of interest to users? In the same way you'd prefer to seen "13 emails" rather than "There are emails".

So either:

*2 notes*

or

*Notes: 2*

Would also be nice if clicking on this line reveals the notes.

Comment: Yes, I like this a lot. I have seen something like "3 comments". But in my case there is just *one* note possible per item. So all I could say is something like "3 paragraphs of notes" or "5 lines of notes".